# Retrieving images from MS Access database and display under <img> form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I save my images in the database as an OLE Object Data type.How can an image from the database displayed in the  tag? Is it also in the 'src' attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In other answer you have been pointed to article explains how to show image in data grid. In general I see here two questions, how to extract an image from the database and how to show it in  tag. The article from Andras Toth answer covers both questions. But if you are not going to use grids, you should provide url to the image in  tag. [Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/123/Storing-Files-and-Images-in-Access-with-ASP.NET) you can read how to implement generic handler shows an image stored in the database, so you can add url to the image to any  tag. Solution depends on your needs.